# Removing one of duplicated rows in data frame based on character values in a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a few duplicates which i want to remove, given a specific condition.

I have a column (column_A) which contain a result from an analysis. Some of the ID's in my data frame have two results, and that's how the duplication of ID's occur. I want to keep the row where column_A == "analysisB", if the ID in "id_no" have both "analysisA" and "analysisB" in column_A, otherwise don't delete a row.

(Note that the original data frame I am running this on have multiple other character and numeric columns)

Dummy data:

```
structure(list(id_no = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), column_A = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("analysisA", "analysisB"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id_no", 
"column_A"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this:

```
id_no    column_A
A        analysisA
B        analysisA
B        analysisB
C        analysisB
D        analysisA
D        analysisB
```

Expected output:

```
id_no    column_A
A        analysisA
B        analysisB
C        analysisB
D        analysisB
```

Is there a way to do this with dplyr? I didn't get it to work properly with the conditional filtering with filter().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do it?

```
data.df%>%
group_by(id_no)%>%
mutate(analysis_count=1:n(),singleton=n()==1)%>%
ungroup()%>%
filter(singleton|analysis_count==2)%>%
select(-analysis_count, -singleton)
```

Answer (score 1):

### A data.table way:

---

In your test case you essentially want the **last item for each ID group** so the following data.table one-liner using `tail` will work.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, tail(.SD,1), by=id_no]
```

Will produce:

```
> dt[, tail(.SD,1), by=id_no]
   id_no  column_A
1:     A analysisA
2:     B analysisB
3:     C analysisB
4:     D analysisB
```

---

**Source:**

[data.table documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R` `duplicated`

```
df1[!duplicated(df1$id_no, fromLast = TRUE),]
#   id_no  column_A
#1     A analysisA
#3     B analysisB
#4     C analysisB
#6     D analysisB
```